# Java split a string into two words: Based on even and odd character index

Tags: java, string

For instance, if the string entered was *INTERLEAVED*, then the first string would be *ITREVD* and the second one would be *NELAE*. Do I need to put the user entered string into a character array and assign the values from there?

Comment: a String is a character array (under the hood).  `String.charAt()` will probably help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Put the string into an array.
- Iterate over said array.
- Remember that `index % 2 == 0` if you're at an even letter and `== 1`
  if you're at an odd. (Modulo is the remainder operator.)
- Done!

PS: You should really try to write *something* before posting a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Create two `StringBuilders`. Take the input `String` and loop over it's characters. For index 0 and even indices, get the character from the input and append it to the first `StringBuilder`. For odd indices, get the character from the input and append it to the second `StringBuilder`. You can determine odd/even indices using the modulus operator `%`.

Methods that you might find useful: [`StringBuilder.append(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%29), [`String.charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).